# sfGuardGroup and i18n

Tags: symfony1, sfguard, sfdoctrineguard, symfony-1.4

I use symfony 1.4.11 with Doctrine. I have site, and it has 3 languages. I use sfDoctrineGuardPlugin 4.0.1 , and I have 3 groups of users. In site I show to each user his group, and I need  it show to each user in current language. So I add to sfGuardGroup field i18n behavior, but I do not now, is it good idea? Is there another solution for this?
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with _I need it show to each user in current language_ ? Do you want to list users by language or show the name of groups correctly translated to current user's native language ?

Comment: correctly translated to current user's native language :) I translated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer depends on how you deal actual with i18n, i mostly prefer messages.xml files !

Anyway i would expect sth like this :

```
   /* actions.class.php */
   function executeBla($request){
       $this->myUser = Doctrine_Core::getTable("SfGuardUser")->find(ID);
   }
```

---

```
   /* blaSuccess.php */
   use_helper("I18N");

   // Users Groups translated
   foreach($myUser->getGroupNames() as $group){
       echo __($group);
   }
```

You'll find sufficient information in symfony's docu :

- http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/13-I18n-and-L10n#chapter_13_text_information_in_the_database
- http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/19

Comment: I try it ?but it is not work for me, so I add i18n column to the my sfGuardGroup table. And it is work) thank you<  for your response.